# What is the correct way of passing context reference between classes?

Tags: android, android-context

In my application I am referring context in different places including Intents , accessing resources ,file operations, AlertDialog etc. And also its difficult to pass current context across different classes. So I tried to set the application base context in a singleton class from the launcher activity. So , while launching application I'm getting application context and setting it in a class. Later I am referring to the same instance of that context. But in some places like `AlertDialog` it gives error if I am using base context. So , is it a good practice to keep the context in a common place and accessing same instead of passing current context among different classes? Or what is the preffered way of passing context while communicating among different classes?

This is my class for getting context

```
public class AppContext extends Application {
    private static Context sContext = null;
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return sContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But in some places like AlertDialog it gives error if I am using base context

You are not allowed to show dialogs from application context. You can do that only using `Activity` context.

> So , is it a good practice to keep the context in a common place and accessing same instead of passing current context among different classes?

It depends on the type of the context. If this is an application context, you can store that in a singleton if you really want to. If it's an `Activity` context you should pass it via reference and be careful when storing this reference somewhere to avoid memory leaks.

> Or what is the preffered way of passing context while communicating among different classes?

It's okay to pass `Context` as a parameter. It is okay to store a reference to this `Context` as long as it's safe to do it.

For example, it is not safe to start an `AsyncTask` and hold a reference to `Activity` context from there because `AsyncTask` has its own lifecycle and it will prevent `Activity` from being Garbage Collected on screen rotation. That will cause a memory leak. In this case it is better to have a `WeakReference` to activity context.

So, my point is, you can pass a context as a parameter wherever you want. If you want to keep a reference to a context - be careful.

Comment: Is it recommended to use getActivity() while using fragments? Because I need to get the parent class reference in fragment. So one way is while starting the parent activity I can set its context in singleton and refer the same in child fragments. Is it safe?

Comment: Fragment always has a reference to activity it is attached to. So it's absolutely ok to store reference to activity from your fragment, just make sure to set it to `null` in `onDetach`. `getActivity()` is a normal approach for getting a context inside your fragment. I strongly don't recommend storing activity context in a singleton because it will be really hard to avoid memory leaks in this case. It's okay to store application context there, but not an activity one.

Comment: okay , but I'm a bit confused which pattern i should follow. Because now I feel difficult to pass context among different classes , especially through nested function calls. Thats why I went for singleton. Also I was thinking like remove platform related parameters from function arguments , so that function calls look more generic. what is your opinion? or can u suggest a pattern to follow?

Comment: can you give an example of "nested function calls" that require a context? I need a use case

Comment: For example I have all file related operation in a separate class. And i have One method say `saveObject` to save object instance inside my model class , 
 and I am calling this save call from activity class. So first  I have to pass Context of activity class to `saveObject`  like `object.SaveObject(this)`
 then inside `saveObject` method , again navigating to file operation class like 'FileHandler.writeFile(this , context)`
and the File handler function also takes this context , like `public static writeFile(Object obj , Context context)`

Comment: You can use application context here, no need to pass activity context that many times because you are not interacting with the UI. Also, the thing that looks weird to me, is that model requires a context to save itself somewhere. Such logic should go to controller, I think

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a setter method that takes in a `Context` for its parameters, and then insert `this` for its Context in the desired class.

From there, you should be able to use that `Context` no matter what class you are in because you stored it as a variable.

Optionally, if you don't want to do that, you can also do this :

```
public static Context contextA;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        contextA = this;
    }
```

Both should work fine.